# Jacobian diagonal computation in JAX

Tags: python, deep-learning, jax, automatic-differentiation

I was wondering how we could use jax (https://github.com/google/jax) to compute a mapping of the derivative.

That is to say :
we have a vector  [image]   and we want to apply (with the jax framework) a function to it, we call it [image] and it's a function  [image]

My question is : how can we easily retrieve the vector :

> [image]

For exemple :

```py
from jax import random
from jax import jacfwd, jacrev
import jax.numpy as jnp

key = random.PRNGKey(0)

key, W_key, b_key, input_key = random.split(key, 4)
W = random.normal(W_key, (10, 10))
b = random.normal(b_key, (10, ))
input = random.normal(input_key, (10, ))
```

One easy way to do that will be to take diagonal of the jacobian, but this method is very slow for high dimensional vector (> 10000). I am only interested in the diagonal of the jacobian ...

```py
def f(input):
  return jnp.dot(W, input) + b

J = jacfwd(f, argnums=0)(input)

result = jnp.diagonal(J)
```

For recall the jabobian matrix is :

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

There's not really a natural way to do this with JAX's transforms: you cannot simply map the input, because in general each diagonal entry of the jacobian depends on *all* inputs.

But given your particular function, you could compute the diagonal of the jacobian directly by rewriting the function like this:

```python
from jax import vmap, grad

def f_single(val, i, W=W, b=b, input=input):
  return jnp.dot(W[i], input.at[i].set(val)) + b[i]

idx = jnp.arange(len(input))

# equivalent to f(input)
print(vmap(f_single)(input, idx))
# [-1.5965443 -1.4081277  1.866176  -0.9789318  2.6717818 -1.0995009
#  -2.3647223  3.6962256  3.3946664  2.589026 ]

# equivalent to jnp.diagonal(jacrev(f)(input))
print(vmap(grad(f_single))(input, idx))
# [-0.87553114  0.543098    2.265052    0.1403018  -1.4744948   1.4401387
#   0.4466088   0.72063404 -0.9135868   0.34965768]
```

Comment: Thanks you Jakevdp ! I didn't expect someone to answer, this was kind of technical. My function is of course a lot more complicated ... (it's a CNN)